# Why doesn't ternary operator work with undefined as falsy in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I looked around and didn't find anyone asking this question, which I find somewhat surprising. Maybe I'm just missing something here, but I have the following code:

```
return $type_cnts ? JSON.parse($type_cnts)[premType] : 0;
```

which to my throws

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $type_cnts is not defined
```

Shouldn't the fact that `$type_cnts` is undefined make it false and thus make the ternary operator return zero?

Comment: Can you post the context code?

Comment: `$typec_cnts !== $type_cnts` The error message is giving you the answer.

Comment: If it is not defined you can not use a ternary operator to test for its existence without typeof unless it is global, than you can use dot notation

Comment: Probably downvoted for the typo(fair enough). However with the typo fixed, the same thing happens. The answer from @clabe45 below is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, undeclared variables throw `ReferenceError`s when you try to access them. However, if you declare the variable with no value,

```
var $type_cnts;
```

then you're ternary operator will work:

```
$type_cnts ? JSON.parse($type_cnts)[premType] : 0; // 0
```

Additionally, undefined properties of objects do not throw errors when you try to access them (common knowledge). And this applies to the `window` object, so if you change your code to

```
window.$type_cnts ? JSON.parse($type_cnts)[premType] : 0;  // no error
```

and even not declare `$type_cnts`, then your code will not throw an error.

Comment: And you have the typo

Comment: @epascarello where?

Comment: typec_counts should be type_cnts. Fixed in question above.